# Angulajs ui-view with 100% full screen height

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am creating a web app using angularjs. I have added the navigation, content and footer in index.html. so ui-view will change the route accordingly. I want to show full screen background image for main page and the rest of the page will only show according to their content.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div ng-include="'views/common/navigation.html'"></div>

<!-- Main view  -->
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div ng-include="'views/common/footer.html'"></div>
```

Here is the HTML will show in ui-view and want to show 100% height. It does not show 100% height. If I up it in index.html it is showing 100% background image width. May I know which one is causing the issue.

```html
<header class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="brand-heading">Grayscale</h1>
                    <p class="intro-text">A free, responsive, one page Bootstrap theme.<br>Created by Start Bootstrap.</p>
                    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

```css
.intro {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the height to 100% on the body (and possibly all parent elements too)

alternatively, try the new viewport height CSS unit ...

height: 100vh

see https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

supports looks good ...

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Yes, I have already set the html, body { height: 100%; } but it is not working. It is strange issue.

Comment: needs to be 100% on all parents not just html, body